# Sql distinct and group by boolean field

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count the distinct occurrences of some column grouped and non-grouped by two boolean columns

```
select count(Distinct some_column) as Uniques, sum(some_other_col)
from myTable T
where T.created_at>'2016-09-15'
group by T.col1, T.col2
```

This query gives four values

```
uniques when col1=true and col2=true
uniques when col1=true and col2=false
uniques when col1=false and col2=true
uniques when col1=false and col2=false
```

Is it possible to change the same query and to get these three values?
I can't get that info combining the first 4 values

```
uniques  (all)
uniques when col1=true 
uniques when col2=true
```

UPDATE

Actually I want to keep the **group by** because there are some other values that I get the sum.

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select count(Distinct some_column) as Uniques,
       count(distinct case when t.col1 then some_column end) as Uniques_col1_true,
       count(distinct case when t.col2 then some_column end) as Uniques_col2_true
from myTable t
where t.created_at > '2016-09-15';
```

Comment: @albert . . . No.  It gives the three that you ask for.  However, you can add additional conditions to get all the values you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN col1 = TRUE
           AND col2 = TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS opt1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN col1 = TRUE
           AND col2 = FALSE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS opt2,
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT col1,
                     col2,
                     somecolumn
     FROM TABLE T
     WHERE ...) AS TB
```